# iOS:Retrieve data from function input parameter

Tags: ios

I want to know how to retrieve the values by giving input parameter to a function. I want to retrieve in this way here as below, but it doesn't retrieve it rather giving empty array value when printing. I can't use even ampersand like c in parameter.

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

MyClass *myClassObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myClassObj getVals : firstArray : secondArray];
NSLog(@"firstArray: %@", firstArray); // empty
            NSLog(@"secondArray: %@", secondArray); // empty

    // function to retrieve 
    - (void) getVals :(NSMutableArray *) firstArray :(NSMutableArray *) secondArray
    {
        firstArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"val1", @"val2", @"val3", @"val4", nil];
        secondArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"val11", @"val22", @"val33", @"val44", nil];


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void) getVals :(NSMutableArray *) firstArray :(NSMutableArray *) secondArray {
    [firstArray addObjectsFromArray:@[ @"val1", @"val2", @"val3", @"val4" ]];
    [secondArray addObjectsFromArray:@[ @"val11", @"val22", @"val33", @"val44" ]];
}
```

The code you have assigns a new array to the local parameter values instead of adding values to the passed in arrays.

Your other option could be:

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = nil;
NSMutableArray *secondArray = nil;

MyClass *myClassObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myClassObj getVals : &firstArray : &secondArray];

- (void) getVals :(NSMutableArray **) firstArray :(NSMutableArray **) secondArray {
    *firstArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"val1", @"val2", @"val3", @"val4", nil];
    *secondArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"val11", @"val22", @"val33", @"val44", nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the object reference with new object. U should rather use

```
[firstArray addObject:@"val1"]
```